# Iterate over clients in Signalr

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, signalr

Is there a way to iterate over clients in SignalR

```
All clients under a hub 

All clients under a group 

All client a user is connected to
```

My goal is to get connection id in each loop and process on them one by one.

```
var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
var allClients = hubContext.Clients.All;
var clientsOfGroup = allClients.Group(groupName);
```

I am trying the above code and iterating allClients and clientsOfGroup and both are throwing errors.

Is there any way to get connection ids collection with SignalR?

EDIT:

If I run the following code:

```
   foreach (var client in allClients)
   {

   }
```

I get this exception:

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'Cannot
>   Implicitly convert type 'Microsoft. Asp Net. SignalR. Hubs. ClientProxy' to
>   'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are
>   you missing a cast?)'

and if I run this:

```
foreach (var client in clientsOfGroup)
{

}
```

I get following exception

```
>     Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<object>' to
> 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are
> you missing a cast?)'
```

Comment: _"both are throwing errors"_ - why don't you tell us what the errors are.

Comment: Please share the exception here

Comment: Edited with exceptions

Comment: Can you please let us know why would you iterate over clients ? Do you want to send some message to all ?

Comment: I know how to send messages etc. My goal is to iterate and process them and do some custom logic.

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind signalR clients is that it does not implement IEnumerable interface thus making it impossible to iterate over online users.

But I would suggest making something custom to overwrite some of the signalR capabilities. So you have two ways I guess!

One is to save users data in database on your hub class and iterate over your connections saved in database or follow these blog here to make use of ajax call to track users.

1. [Blog link 1](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/asp-net/tracking-online-users-with-signalr/)
2. [Blog link 2](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/asp-net/tracking-online-users/?article=2240)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over connections using reflection.

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Linq;

...

var connMan = Clients.All.GetType().GetField("_lifetimeManager", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(Clients.All);
var connsObj = connMan.GetType().GetField("_connections", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(connMan);
ConcurrentDictionary<string, HubConnectionContext> conns = (ConcurrentDictionary<string, HubConnectionContext>)connsObj.GetType().GetField("_connections", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(connsObj);
Console.WriteLine("Current connections: " + String.Join(",", conns.Values.ToList().Select(i => i.ConnectionId)));
```